# JPA : one table with primary key and another table with primary and foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I started studing JPA by reading a book and they gave an unidirection mapping which is like this:

table ***vehicle***

```
(vehicleId, brand, model, dev_year, extraId)
```

> **vehicleId** is the PK, 
>   **extraId** is the FK

table ***travel_extra***

`(id, allowSmoke, allowFood, allowDrinks, airConditioner)`

> ***id*** is the PK

Then the java objects:

```
public class Vehicle {

   @Id
   private long vehicleId;
   private String brand;
   private String model;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")
   private TravelExtra travelExtra;
}


public class TravelExtra {

     @Id
     private id;

     private boolean allowSmoke;
     private boolean allowFood;
     private boolean allowDrinks;
     private boolean airConditioner; 

}
```

When i *persist* and *commit* the transaction it works like a charm.

However! for my case i don't want the **vehicle** table to have a foreign key but i want the foreign key to be in the **travel_extra** table and link to the primary key of vehicle table. BUT when i do that the code doesnt work and no matter what i try to do i can not make it work.

If somebody has ever experianced such thing i will be happy for some assitance and examples of how to make it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA: Foreign key that is also a primary key mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305950/jpa-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-mapping)

Comment: You should edit your first question which already has 2 valid suggestions.

Comment: The suggestions are not very accurate so i decided to ask the question a little bit differently

Comment: I will try to combine the questions into one later...

Comment: I would suggest it was your question that was not very accurate. You now want a FK in travel_extra. A minute ago it was a shared primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `@JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId", insertable = false, updateable = false)`, and create a `vehicleID` column in `TravelExtra` table. `insertable = false, updateable = false` should instruct ORM to look for the column in target table.

**EDIT**

My reference is [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys), where it states:

> In JPA the JoinColumn defines an **insertable** and **updatable** attribute, these can be used to instruct the JPA provider that the foreign key is actually in the target object's table

If it doesn't work (since it is not guaranteed by the specification), you can make the relation bidirectional (just add a mapping in `TravelExtra` entity, no further database changes needed)

```
public class Vehicle {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vehicle", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TravelExtra travelExtra;
    ...
}

public class TravelExtra {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleId")
    private Vehicle vehicle;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is what i got: 
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'vehicleId' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO travel_extra (primaryKeyId, airConditioner, allowDrinks, allowFood, allowSmoke, luggage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Core.TravelExtra[ primaryKeyId=1 ])

Comment: I dont want the TravelExtra to have a reference to Vehicle

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to inflate your Vehicle class with reference to VehicleExtra information (id), since Vehicle is completely independent of VehicleExtra, only VehicleExtra needs to be aware of Vehicle.

[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305950/jpa-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-mapping/61130857#61130857)