# JPA / Hibernate: create a primary key which is a primary key of another table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

I have this simple `User`  entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fdei_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String login;
}
```

I would like to create a second table `UserDetail` with fields `id` and `property1`.

In this the second table `UserDetail` I do not want a generated incremented id, but I want that the field `id` is the same `id` of the user in the table `User`, and I want that when I fetch the UserDetail id=1, also the User entity with id=1 is fetched.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fdei_user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private User id;

    private Boolean property1;
}
```

How can I realize this?
I tried with @OneToOne, @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, @MapsId...but nothing...I always have errors.

What's the right way?

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: Foreign key that is also a primary key mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305950/jpa-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-mapping)

Comment: YOU CAN REFER  [THIS](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What you are looking for is Unidirectional @OneToOne relationship.
- You need both `@Id` field and a relationship (`User user`) field.
- Please note the usage of `@MapsId` to make sure that there is only one key field in the details table.

I added this answer, as none of the sources posted in comments had reference to `@MapsId`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fdei_user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    private Boolean property1;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: when I try to add a record in the UserDetails, I have an error from Hibernate: "null identifier" even if the field "id" is validated. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: How do you set the `id`? With this setup, I think you need to set the `user` field.

Comment: When I persist an UserDetails row, I set the "Long id" with an existing id in the User table, and I set also the user.setId() with the same "Long id"...

Comment: I believe this is overcomplcating things. Just set the `user` field in the new `UserDetails` object and you are good to go. The user must be attached to context. User u1 = userRepository.findOne(1L);
UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
ud.setUser(u1);
userDetailsRepository.save(ud);

Comment: Solved with:  `@Id
    private Long id;
 
 @OneToOne
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
 private User user;` without `@OneToOne` and without `@MapsId`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fdei_user_details")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

    private Boolean property1;

    // getters and setters
}
```

you can annotate @Id on the mapping itself (JPA 2.0)