# Using primary key of one table as foreign key to another table

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Lets say I have the following SQL table definitions:

```sql
create table overview (
   key          bigserial not null,
   supplemental decimal(20) not null,
   constraint overview_pk primary key (key)
);
create table details (
   key        decimal(20) not null,
   ver        decimal(20) not null,
   constraint details_pk primary key (key, ver)
);
```

Furthermore I have two appropriate JPA mapping classes like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "overview")
public class Overview implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "key", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal key;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private BigDecimal supplemental;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "overview")
  private Details details;

  public Overview() {
  }

  public Overview(BigDecimal supplemental, Details details) {
    this.details = details;
    this.details.setOverview(this);
  }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "details")
public class Details implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
  protected BigDecimal key;

  @Column(name = "ver", nullable = false)
  protected BigDecimal ver;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId(value = "key")
  private Overview overview;

  public Details() {
  }

  public Overview getOverview() {
    return overview;
  }

  public void setOverview(Overview overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
  }


}
```

The intention is to have a single key generation in Table `overview` and use that key for two things. First as foreign key in `details` table and as primary key for `overview` table as well.

One question is: Is this possible with Hibernate / Spring Data JPA? [Based on what I have read it should be?](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

I have some test code which save things into `overview`, `details` tables but always fail with a error message like this:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing 
: xyz.modell.Overview.details 
-> xyz.modell.Details
```

Maybe someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: overview table has a pk on key column and details table has pk on key and ver columns which is a combination key. So referring pk of overview table as foreign key in details table is not possible for a combination key on (key, ver).

Comment: The duplicate to the question in the title is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305950/jpa-foreign-key-that-is-also-a-primary-key-mapping

Comment: The `details` table has a composite primary key - jpa should reflect that. I remember doing this "one part of the composite primary key is a foreign key" thing once (hence, it's possible) but... do not do it: just add a unique id to your `details` table and change the primary key to an unique index: you'll live a happier life