# How to add a OneToOne relationship inside a child entity and map the Id of its parent

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Consider a Java entity called `Profile`:

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String firstname;

}
```

And consider another entity called `ProfilePicture`.

Each `Profile` has exactly one `ProfilePicture`. The `ProfilePicture`, however, is optional. I want to establish a `@OneToOne` relationship between `Profile` and `ProfilePicture` and I wonder which of the two entities would be the owning entity, i.e. the parent.

My first thought was: Since each `Profile` has a `ProfilePicture` and not the other way round, the `Profile` owns the `ProfilePicture` and is, therefore, the parent. Therefore, I would add the following entry to `Profile`:

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String firstname;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "picture_id")
  ProfilePicture picture;

}
```

Now, I have come across the `@MapsId` annotation and I wonder, if I could instead change the `ProfilePicture`:

```
@Entity
public class ProfilePicture {

    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    Byte[] picture;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    @MapsId
    Profile profile;
}
```

I would like the `ProfilePicture` to have the same id as the corresponding `Profile`. I am not sure, however, if - with the last shown option - the `Profile` still owns the `ProfilePicture`, as now the profile is declared as a variable inside the ProfilePicture entity. Can somebody help me out, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` in the `ProfilePicture` entity to map your foreign key and primary key.

```
@Entity
public class ProfilePicture {
    @Id
    Long id;

    Byte[] picture;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="picture_id")
    Profile profile;
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27306662/6784846

Comment: It worked.Thank you.